# When I add the shipping line item that was selected to the orders view in commerce it duplicates orders

Tags: commerce

This seems to be related to how many products were in the order, as adding this shipping line item from the order to the view it shows every product that that applies to.

Is there a way to change the settings in views to only show the one listing that shows the shipping option and hide all the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I found this module called [Views Grouping Row Limit](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views_limit_grouping-7.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz) which works

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you might just need to learn more how database queries work, as the relationship you've added to your View is what's creating multiple rows. You can filter by any value you want to weed out "duplicates", including line item types, reference field delta values, etc. to ensure there's only one row per record. I'm not exactly sure what you're getting out of grouping, but some filtering option may give you better results - worth looking into! : )